# Issue in executing parameterised query inside stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure in which I'm executing a query. When I execute the query it returns multiple rows instead of one. But when I execute the same query without the store procedure it returns single row. Since I'm new to MySQL I'm facing issues in declaring variables inside stored procedures and using them.

I'm calling the stored procedure from C# code.

```
Stored procedure code(returns multiple values):
CREATE PROCEDURE `USP_UPDATE_BLACKLIST_RECORD_DETAIL`(
FILE_NAME varchar(100)
)
BEGIN

SET @FILE_NAME=null; SET @FILE_NAME = FILE_NAME;
SET @UPDATE_CODE = null; SET @ACTUAL_RECORD_COUNT = null;

/*Get the update code of the extracted file*/
SET @UPDATE_CODE = (SELECT count(UPDATE_CODE) FROM TX_BLACKLIST_FILE_DETAIL WHERE FILE_NAME = @FILE_NAME );

select @UPDATE_CODE;
END

Query without stored procedure(returns single value):
set @FILE_NAME=null;
set @FILE_NAME='TPCCH_ULEPL_20141112_164635.BLT';
set @UPDATE_CODE=null;
set @ACTUAL_RECORD_COUNT=null;

/*Get the update code of the extracted file*/
SET @UPDATE_CODE = (SELECT count(UPDATE_CODE) FROM TX_BLACKLIST_FILE_DETAIL WHERE FILE_NAME = @FILE_NAME );

select @UPDATE_CODE;

end
```

Comment: are you passing 'TPCCH_ULEPL_20141112_164635.BLT' in stored procedure ? are you getting multiple rows of same result data?what kind of multiple rows you are getting

Comment: Yes, passing the file name 'TPCCH_ULEPL_20141112_164635.BLT' in stored procedure. The count should return only 1, but it returns count of all rows in the table.

Comment: It's not considering the variable comparison in the query.

Comment: Provide more detail. There is no way COUNT can return multiple rows unless grouping is involved.

Comment: where you declare @UPDATE_CODE and @ACTUAL_RECORD_COUNT?

Comment: Try to use SET @FILE_NAME = 'TPCCH_ULEPL_20141112_164635.BLT'; instead of  SET FILE_NAME = FILE_NAME; in your stored procedure and execute. if not work try Another option also ,give different name to temporary variable and use input variable directly in WHERE clause , no need to assign value of input parameter to temporary variable.

Comment: It did not work Disha. Do I need to put quotes FILE_NAME = ''+@FILE_NAME_N+'' since it is comparing a string value.